# Строчная/прописная?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Все-таки со строчной или прописной следует писать слово "филиал" в предложении "Справка Ф(ф)илиала Центрального архива Министерства обороны РФ (военно-медицинских документов)"? В работах историков мне встречаются оба варианта написания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно предположить, что в данном случае правильным будет написание с прописной буквы: ***Филиал** Центрального архива Министерства обороны РФ (военно-медицинских документов).* Дело в том, что такой филиал (военно-медицинских документов) только один.

А вот территориальных филиалов много, поэтому там больше подходит строчная буква, например: Адрес ***филиала** Центрального архива Министерства Обороны РФ=ЦАМО в г. Пугачев:*
413700, Саратовская область, г. Пугачев, в/ч 61220.

**Пояснение** (как применяется правило выбора буквы)

1. Если такой филиал единственный, то в состав имени собственного входит слово "филиал" и пишется с прописной буквы **как первое слово названия.**
2. Если филиалов с точно таким названием много, то следует считать слово "филиал" нарицательным и писать **со строчной буквы**, что обычно и делается в тексте (в справках, например).

Прописная буква пишется только в качестве **начальной** (в предложении, в перечне и т. д.).

3. **Откуда берутся варианты письма**? Статус документов (записей) может быть разный. В таких ситуациях специалист в конкретной области может иногда лучше сориентироваться, если он понимает разницу между нарицательными и собственными именами.

Надо видеть **официальное название** конкретного учреждения. Не очень логично включать адрес в такое официальное название, но не учитывать такой вариант тоже нельзя.

https://archive.mil.ru/archival_service/central/history/structure.htm

https://otvet.mail.ru/question/40646719